# How to write data in a tabular form in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I am using python 2.7 I want to write data to a file in a tabular form in a file. Table contains three columns. And this file will be accessed by different applications. So, this file will remain in the system.

I have to both read and write data. So data should be easily accessible just like sql database.

Comment: What have yiou tried? Got any code?

Comment: why not an sql database? like... sqlite?

Answer (score 4):

### Using SQLite

The [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) module stores sql tables in a single file, without requiring a webserver for access like mySQL.

**Writing**

```
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
             (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')

# Insert a row of data
c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()
```

To change and remove data you can use the regular SQL statements like `UPDATE`, `SET`, `DELETE`

**Reading**

```
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
print c.fetchone()
```

**Closing**

```
# We can also close the connection if we are done with it.
# Just be sure any changes have been committed or they will be lost.
conn.close()
```

---

### Using CSV

The [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module lets you read and write lists and tables. It's a standard format supported by pretty much every spreadsheet application and programming language.

**Writing**

```
import csv

with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

results in:

> Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam |Baked Beans|
>
> Spam |Lovely Spam| |Wonderful Spam|

**Loading**

```
import csv

with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
for row in spamreader:
    print ', '.join(row)
```

prints:

> Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
>
> Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam

Comment: how to add new row (add 3rd row if 2 rows are already present), and also delete a row

Comment: Instead of adding new rows, it deletes previous rows, and then add new row. Previous rows should also present and should removed only when deleted

Comment: Csv doesn't provide this functionality. It should be used together with your own data structure. e.g.: Read the file into a list of rows containing a list of its fields. After the data is changed use the writer to save the changes.

Comment: If you need something more advanced for a larger dataset that is changed often look into [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: can u please explain how to do it

Comment: The csv way or the sqlite way? How often does the data change, how many programs will access it at same time? Are you familiar with SQL?

Comment: I want to maintain a file only and no database for it. Two programs will use it. I know SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module implements classes to read and write tabular data in CSV format. It allows programmers to say, “write this data in the format preferred by Excel,” or “read data from this file which was generated by Excel,” without knowing the precise details of the CSV format used by Excel. Programmers can also describe the CSV formats understood by other applications or define their own special-purpose CSV formats.

The csv module’s reader and writer objects read and write sequences. Programmers can also read and write data in dictionary form using the DictReader and DictWriter classes.

Answer (score 0):

**To write**

```
myList = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
with open('/home/XXXX/whatever.txt', 'w') as file:
    for row in myList:
        file.write(';'.join(row))
        file.write('\n')
```

**To read**

```
myList2 = list()
with open('/home/XXXX/whatever.txt', 'r') as file:
    for row in file.read().splitlines():
        myList2.append(row.split(';'))
```

Comment: There's also `r+` to do both operations on a file.

Comment: Instead of adding new rows, it deletes previous rows, and then add new row. Previous rows should also present and should removed only when deleted. How to add new row (add 3rd row if 2 rows are already present), and also delete a row